# Is there an idiomatic way to dry up repeated method calls in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

When the same call is made repeatedly in the same describe block e.g.

```
RSpec.describe Grant do
  let(:grant) { Grant.make }

  describe "#exchange!" do
    it "destroys token" do
      grant.exchange! # dry me up!
      expect(grant).to be_destroyed
    end
    it "returns a Token" do
      expect(grant.exchange!).to be_a(Token) # dry me up!
    end
  end
end
```

I want to dry up `grant.exchange!`

I've worked out how to do it with `subject`, but I know explicit subjects are smelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`let!`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) to define a memoized helper that is executed before each example:

```
RSpec.describe Grant do
  let(:grant) { Grant.make }

  describe "#exchange!" do
    let!(:result) { grant.exchange! }

    it "destroys token" do
      expect(grant).to be_destroyed
    end

    it "returns a Token" do
      expect(result).to be_a(Token)
    end
  end
end
```

However, I personally prefer to call the method explicitly from within the example, just like in your code. It makes it easier to deal with the state before and after the invocation.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. This is what I ended up doing.